# Iterate over map and run method on each result - APEX

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, apex-code

I'm looking to check the field level security of all of the fields on the Opportunity object.
So I'm getting the full map of fields and storing them in a static variable so I can access them from where ever I need.

```
private static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> myMap;

private static void initMaps() {
    myMap = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields.getMap();
}
```

I want to iterate over all of the fields on the object and check .isAccessible() on each.
I'm a little stuck as to how to iterate over the fields however, and also how to check .isAccessible() on eash.

```
//THIS BIT DOESN'T WORK...
private doCheckMap(myMap){
    for (Id key : myMap.keySet()) {
        if(false == Schema.SObjectType.???.fields.isAccessible()) {
            System.debug('nope!');
        }     
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: You have Schema.sObjectType instead of You have Schema.SObjectType.

Comment: I have Schema.sObjectType instead of what??

Comment: lol, sorry I had a CVA writing that. Just wanted to mention that you had Schema.sObjectType instead of Schema.SObjectType. Don't know if it was a typo or an error in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through yout map like this:

```
Map<String, MyType> myMap = new HashMap<String, MyType>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, MyType>> iter = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    MyType entry = iter.next().getValue();
    for (Field f : entry.getClass().getFields()) {
          if (f.isAccessible()) {
              //...
          }
    }
}
```

Then again why do you even need a map? Couldn'you just use reflexion api getFields() - like this:

```
for (Field f : Opportunity.getClass().getFields()) {
    if (f.isAccessible()) {
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Took a tiny bit of tweaking but works fine for me now. Cheers rob, much appreciated!